# Vue Custom dropdown not showing on modal

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I've installed a module from https://desislavsd.gitbook.io and used it for my custom modal. However I have trouble the dropdown is not overlapping and stuck in here even adjusting `z-index:999` does not do anything.

I also tried to make adjustments to the height but upon clicking the custom component but doesn't work because if I already make the height of the modal higher before the dropdown list is shown it would leave a big space below they dropdown which is not friendly looking.

Custom module https://jsfiddle.net/desislavsd/es2n6py0/

Either adjusting the height of the modal onclick will do or overlapping the dropdown as long as the lists are shown.

```js
    <div class="filter-body-w-auto shadows-box p-0 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-9" v-if="getSelectedFilterType == 'connectivity'">
        <div class="filter-header">
            <h6>Connectivity</h6>
            <div class="filter-close-btn" @click="hideModal('')">
                <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row pt-1 px-2 mt-0 mb-2 mx-1 justify-content-evenly">
            <p class="text-dark text-start mt-1 mb-0 mx-0 py-1 px-0" style="font-size: 100%;">Available to All Tenants</p>
            <v-select v-model="selected.browsers" as="name:id:id" :from="browsers" tagging :tag-keys="[9,32,188]"></v-select>
        </div>
    </div>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!-- Inspector code -->

<div data-v-796ce895="" class="filter-body-w-auto shadows-box p-0 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <div data-v-796ce895="" class="filter-header">
        <h6 data-v-796ce895="">Connectivity</h6>
        <div data-v-796ce895="" class="filter-close-btn">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-796ce895="" class="row filter-tags pt-1 px-2 mt-0 mb-2 mx-1 justify-content-evenly">
        <p data-v-796ce895="" class="text-dark text-start mt-1 mb-0 mx-0 py-1 px-0" style="font-size: 100%;">Available
            to All Tenants</p>
        <div data-v-796ce895="" tabindex="-1" class="v-select -empty -multiple">
            <div class="v-select-bar">
                <div class="v-select-inp-group"><input placeholder="Search.." class="v-select-inp"><button type="button"
                        tabindex="-1" class="v-select-btn-clear"></button><button type="button" tabindex="-1"
                        class="v-select-btn-dd"></button><button type="button" tabindex="-1"
                        class="v-select-btn-spinner"></button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v-select-list">
                <span class="v-select-option">Internet Explorer</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Firefox</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Chrome</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Safari</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera3</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera2</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera2</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera1</span>
                <span class="v-select-option">Opera11</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.filter-body-w-auto[data-v-796ce895] {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    top: 400px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.filter-header[data-v-796ce895] {
    background: #466cb3;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

3rd party css module: https://github.com/desislavsd/vue-select/blob/master/dist/vue-select.css
Btw I also have used some bootstrap classes in here mixed with custom styles

[image]

Awkward design but another possible solution if overlap does not work
[image]

Comment: Huge mix of different CSS sources here, hard to pinpoint what is happening without being able to inspect it. But what happens if you get rid of the inline-block on the filter body? I think it could prevent things from displaying properly and doesn't seem to be necessary here.

Comment: @anatolhiman unfortunately it does not do anything when removing the inline-block. it only adjusts the position of the modal

Comment: @anatolhiman would it be possible to add detection from custom vue component on click ? so that I can extend the height of the div when dropdown shows?

Comment: Set `overflow-y: visible` on modal.

Comment: I've set `overflow-y: visible` main div of modal. but the problem is that it would add a scroll bar to the whole modal reaching up to the header but with this I'm able to get the contents of dropdown by scrolling.

Comment: Yes, you could set a min-height on the modal body when user clicks in the search field. That's maybe the best compromise, because you probably know how many rows the search result will show (max). But disallowing scrolling is negative for accessibility, you never know what kind of (small) screen a user is on and how huge their text or what their zoom level are. But if selecting a search result item closes the modal and displays it on the page behind, then preventing scroll and expanding the search box on input focus seems like a good idea.

Comment: Bootstrap modals have a high z-index (1040 or more). Could you try `.v-select .v-select-list { z-index: 1500; }` and let me know if it works?